# Crash while using Core Haptics most probably while stopping the Haptic Engine

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, exc-bad-access, haptic-feedback

I am using `Core Haptics` in my application to implement custom vibrations which could not be done by using simple `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator`
Then i do the following -

1. Instantiate the engine
2. Start the engine
3. Instantiate the CHHapticPatternPlayer
4. Start the player

Function to play vibration -

```
func playContinuousVibration() {
    do {
        let pattern = try continuousVibration()
        try hapticEngine.start()
        let player = try hapticEngine.makePlayer(with: pattern)
        try player.start(atTime: CHHapticTimeImmediate)
        hapticEngine.notifyWhenPlayersFinished { _ in
            return .stopEngine
        }
    } catch {}
}
```

Firebase Crash Stack Trace

> Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos EXC_BAD_ACCESS
> KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010
>
> CoreHaptics
> __31-[CHHapticEngine handleFinish:]_block_invoke.306 + 276
>
> libdispatch.dylib
> _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
>
> libsystem_pthread.dylib start_wqthread + 8

Edit 1 - Posting the entire class code here to give the readers more context

```
final class CustomHapticFeedback {
    private let duration: Int
    private let amplitude: SwFeedbackImpactType?
    private var coreHapticsManager: Any? //Purposely made as Any to avoid using #available keyword everywhere
    
    init(duration: Int, amplitude: String) {
        self.duration = duration
        self.amplitude = SwFeedbackImpactType(rawValue: amplitude)
    }
    
    //This function will perform either UIKit haptic feedback or Core Haptics feedback depending on device and OS compatibility
    func performVibrateAction() {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            guard CHHapticEngine.capabilitiesForHardware().supportsHaptics else {
                performUIKitHapticFeedback()
                return
            }
            performCoreHapticFeedback()
        } else {
            performUIKitHapticFeedback()
        }
    }
    
    private func performUIKitHapticFeedback() {
        if let amplitude = amplitude {
            SwHaptic.impact(amplitude.value).generate()
        }
    }
    
    private func performCoreHapticFeedback() {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            /*
             Currently Core Haptics is not being used anywhere else apart from Gamification flow hence creating a new instance of
             CoreHapticsManager everytime. Once this is being used in multiple places we can think of persisting it
             */
            coreHapticsManager = CoreHapticsManager(duration: duration, amplitude: amplitude ?? .light)
            if let manager = coreHapticsManager as? CoreHapticsManager {
                manager.playContinuousVibration()
            }
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
final class CoreHapticsManager {
    private let hapticEngine: CHHapticEngine
    private let duration: Int
    private let amplitude: SwFeedbackImpactType
    
    init?(duration: Int, amplitude: SwFeedbackImpactType) {
        self.duration = duration
        self.amplitude = amplitude
        let hapticCapability = CHHapticEngine.capabilitiesForHardware()
        guard hapticCapability.supportsHaptics else {
            return nil
        }
        
        do {
            hapticEngine = try CHHapticEngine()
        } catch _ {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    func playContinuousVibration() {
        do {
            let pattern = try continuousVibration()
            try hapticEngine.start()
            let player = try hapticEngine.makePlayer(with: pattern)
            try player.start(atTime: CHHapticTimeImmediate)
            hapticEngine.notifyWhenPlayersFinished { _ in
                return .stopEngine
            }
        } catch {}
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension CoreHapticsManager {
    //Below function will play a continuous vibration for a constant period of time
    private func continuousVibration() throws -> CHHapticPattern {
        let hapticIntensity: Float
        switch amplitude {
        case .light:
            hapticIntensity = 0.7
        case .medium:
            hapticIntensity = 0.85
        case .heavy:
            hapticIntensity = 1.0
        }
        let continuousVibrationEvent = CHHapticEvent(
            eventType: .hapticContinuous,
            parameters: [
                CHHapticEventParameter(parameterID: .hapticIntensity, value: hapticIntensity)
            ],
            relativeTime: 0,
            duration: (Double(duration)/1000))
        return try CHHapticPattern(events: [continuousVibrationEvent], parameters: [])
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

```
enum SwFeedbackImpactType: String {
    case light, medium, heavy
    var value: UIImpactFeedbackGenerator.FeedbackStyle {
        switch self {
        case .light:
            return .light
        case .medium:
            return .medium
        case .heavy:
            return .heavy
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 3: Making Haptic Player a member of the class instead of instantiating inside the function

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
final class CoreHapticsManager {
    private let hapticEngine: CHHapticEngine
    private let duration: Int
    private let amplitude: SwFeedbackImpactType
    private var player: CHHapticPatternPlayer?
    
    init?(duration: Int, amplitude: SwFeedbackImpactType) {
        self.duration = duration
        self.amplitude = amplitude
        let hapticCapability = CHHapticEngine.capabilitiesForHardware()
        guard hapticCapability.supportsHaptics else {
            return nil
        }
        
        do {
            hapticEngine = try CHHapticEngine()
        } catch _ {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    func playContinuousVibration() {
        do {
            let pattern = try continuousVibration()
            try hapticEngine.start()
            player = try hapticEngine.makePlayer(with: pattern)
            try player?.start(atTime: CHHapticTimeImmediate)
            hapticEngine.notifyWhenPlayersFinished { _ in
                return .stopEngine
            }
        } catch {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Apple says: "Create a haptic engine instance. Maintain a strong reference to it so it doesn’t go out of scope while the haptic is playing." You need to keep your `player` alive. Make it a member of the class instead of declaring the variable in the method.

Comment: Hi, try to upload all the code for testing.

Comment: @EricAya Got it. Let me try that.

Comment: @wazowski Have posted more code here for your understanding. Kindly look into it.

Comment: Can you share SwFeedbackImpactType too please

Comment: @wazowski Have added the SwFeedbackImpactType enum as well. Anyway that is used as a fallback in case custom haptics is not compatible with the device/OS so don't think that is coming in the picture here

Comment: @EricAya So here i have already made the engine a member of the class. Are you suggesting i should do the same for the `player` as well?

Comment: @kgupta073 Yes, this is what I'm suggesting. I quoted the part about the engine but it's the same for the player.

Comment: @EricAya Ok. I have made the `player` an optional property of the class instead of instantiating it within the function itself. Can you please check EDIT 3 and tell me if that works?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to play the haptic like this. I have removed extra code for the test, but I think you can reproduce it in your full code, right? Because time, I have tested only for iOS 13 and above.

```
import Foundation

import CoreHaptics

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class HapticManager {
  let hapticEngine: CHHapticEngine

  init?() {
    let hapticCapability = CHHapticEngine.capabilitiesForHardware()
    guard hapticCapability.supportsHaptics else {
      return nil
    }

    do {
      hapticEngine = try CHHapticEngine()
      hapticEngine.isAutoShutdownEnabled = true
    } catch let error {
      print("Haptic engine Creation Error: \(error)")
      return nil
    }
  }
  
  func playPattern() {
    do {
      let pattern = try continuousVibration()
      try hapticEngine.start()
      let player = try hapticEngine.makePlayer(with: pattern)
      try player.start(atTime: CHHapticTimeImmediate)
      hapticEngine.notifyWhenPlayersFinished { _ in
        return .stopEngine
      }
    } catch {
      print("Failed to play pattern: \(error)")
    }
  }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension HapticManager {
  private func basicPattern() throws -> CHHapticPattern {

        let pattern = CHHapticEvent(
          eventType: .hapticTransient,
          parameters: [
            CHHapticEventParameter(parameterID: .hapticIntensity, value: 3.0),
            CHHapticEventParameter(parameterID: .hapticSharpness, value: 3.0)
          ],
          relativeTime: 1)

        return try CHHapticPattern(events: [pattern], parameters: [])
  }
    
    private func continuousVibration() throws -> CHHapticPattern {
        let duration = 1000 // ms suppose
        let hapticIntensity: Float
        hapticIntensity = 1.0
        let continuousVibrationEvent = CHHapticEvent(
            eventType: .hapticContinuous,
            parameters: [
                CHHapticEventParameter(parameterID: .hapticIntensity, value: hapticIntensity)
            ],
            relativeTime: 0,
            duration: (Double(duration)/1000))
        return try CHHapticPattern(events: [continuousVibrationEvent], parameters: [])
    }
}
```

So in order to test you can use playPattern and `continuosVibration` will be fired.

But I think if you want to keep it working you should put it in a while loop with a trigger like this:

```
func startHaptic() {
    sendHaptics = true
    while sendHaptics == true {
      queue.async {
        hapticManager?.playPattern()
      }
    }
  }
```

The `sendHaptics` property must be global, right? and toggle it when no more haptic is needed.